# How to get query results as text?

Tags: jdbc

The API below returns the results in typed format as a `ResultSet` object.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from data;");
```

This is not ideal, if all I want to do is print out the results of the query as text. For that, I need to know the schema of the table, and then extract the data one by one from the `ResultSet` object.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Just run the query and get the results as plaintext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the [number of columns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29) in the result set from [its metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29), then [iterate over the rows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29), and for each row, get each column [as String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29) or [as Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29) and print it.